# Aggregate is returning (some) duplicate items with same ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Our Mongo replication servers experienced a crash because of to many traffic and a query that wasn't optimized. This all has been solved and everything is working correctly, we just have one problem we can't figure out.

While our primary server crashed, some items got added. That went ok, but the weird thing is that these items that where added in the crash window are now returned double in our aggregate queries.

If I'm going a find() query, it doesn't show up. How is this even possible?

Here's our aggregate query:
`

```
[
  {
    '$match': { is_active: true, is_removed: { $ne: true }, _id: { $in: ['390195122352164864'] } }
  },
  { '$sort': { 'list_ranking.default': -1 } },
  { '$limit': 48 },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items',
      localField: 'parent_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'parent'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items_type',
      localField: 'item_type',
      foreignField: 'key',
      as: 'type'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items_rarity',
      localField: 'item_rarity',
      foreignField: 'key',
      as: 'rarity'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items_serie',
      localField: 'item_serie',
      foreignField: 'key',
      as: 'serie'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items_set',
      localField: 'item_set',
      foreignField: 'key',
      as: 'sets'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items_introduction',
      localField: 'item_introduction',
      foreignField: 'key',
      as: 'introduction'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items_background',
      localField: 'item_background',
      foreignField: 'key',
      as: 'background'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'items_set',
      localField: 'parent.item_set',
      foreignField: 'key',
      as: 'parentSets'
    }
  },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$parent', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$type', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$rarity', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$serie', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$sets', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  {
    '$unwind': { path: '$introduction', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': { path: '$background', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': { path: '$parentSets', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      slug: 1,
      'parent.slug': 1,
      name: 1,
      'parent.name': 1,
      description: 1,
      'parent.description': 1,
      key: 1,
      'parent.key': 1,
      icon: 1,
      'parent.icon': 1,
      featured: 1,
      'parent.featured': 1,
      media_id: 1,
      'parent.media_id': 1,
      media_type: 1,
      'parent.media_type': 1,
      media_uploaded_at: 1,
      'parent.media_uploaded_at': 1,
      media_processed_at: 1,
      'parent.media_processed_at': 1,
      list_order: 1,
      'parent.list_order': 1,
      list_ranking: 1,
      'parent.list_ranking': 1,
      rating_good: 1,
      'parent.rating_good': 1,
      rating_bad: 1,
      'parent.rating_bad': 1,
      estimated_available_combos: 1,
      'parent.estimated_available_combos': 1,
      obtained_type: 1,
      'parent.obtained_type': 1,
      obtained_value: 1,
      'parent.obtained_value': 1,
      v3_itemid: 1,
      'parent.v3_itemid': 1,
      v3_itemkey: 1,
      'parent.v3_itemkey': 1,
      v3_mediaid: 1,
      'parent.v3_mediaid': 1,
      is_active: 1,
      'parent.is_active': 1,
      is_released: 1,
      'parent.is_released': 1,
      is_removed: 1,
      'parent.is_removed': 1,
      modified_at: 1,
      'parent.modified_at': 1,
      created_at: 1,
      'parent.created_at': 1,
      'type.slug': 1,
      'type.name': 1,
      'type.key': 1,
      'rarity.slug': 1,
      'rarity.name': 1,
      'rarity.key': 1,
      'rarity.color': 1,
      'serie.slug': 1,
      'serie.name': 1,
      'serie.key': 1,
      'serie.color': 1,
      'sets.slug': 1,
      'sets.name': 1,
      'sets.key': 1,
      'sets.is_active': 1,
      'parentSets.slug': 1,
      'parentSets.name': 1,
      'parentSets.key': 1,
      'parentSets.is_active': 1,
      'background.slug': 1,
      'background.name': 1,
      'background.key': 1,
      'introduction.slug': 1,
      'introduction.name': 1,
      'introduction.key': 1,
      'introduction.chapter': 1,
      'introduction.season': 1,
      'parent._id': 1
    }
  }
]
```

`

And this is what we're getting back:
`

```
[
  {
    _id: '390195122352164864',
    slug: 'ffc-neymar-jr',
    name: 'FFC Neymar Jr',
    description: 'Knows a thing or two.',
    key: 'character_redoasisgooseberry',
    icon: 'b74a4677-e2ba-4f25-9e92-25756dafc9d2',
    featured: 'b422fadb-6960-4122-9d3d-37cbc06501e8',
    media_id: '04ddd281-309e-40e5-811d-767e52d84847',
    media_type: 'video/mp4',
    media_uploaded_at: null,
    media_processed_at: 2022-12-02T07:34:43.371Z,
    obtained_type: 'vbucks',
    obtained_value: '1200',
    rating_good: 101,
    rating_bad: 6,
    list_order: 6396,
    list_ranking: {
      default: 6807,
      last_1_hr: 534,
      last_24_hrs: 6807,
      last_7_days: 7682
    },
    estimated_available_combos: 6,
    is_released: true,
    is_active: true,
    is_removed: false,
    modified_at: null,
    created_at: 2022-11-30T17:36:06.643Z,
    type: { slug: 'outfit', name: 'Outfit', key: 'AthenaCharacter' },
    rarity: {
      slug: 'rare',
      name: 'Rare',
      key: 'EFortRarity::Rare',
      color: '28C4F2'
    },
    serie: {
      slug: 'icon',
      name: 'Icon Series',
      key: 'CreatorCollabSeries',
      color: '5DD6EA'
    },
    sets: {
      is_active: false,
      slug: 'set01',
      name: 'Fortnite Football Club',
      key: 'SphereKickGroup'
    },
    introduction: {
      slug: 'chapter-3-season-4',
      name: 'Introduced in Chapter 3, Season 4.',
      key: 22,
      chapter: '3',
      season: '4'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: '390195122352164864',
    slug: 'ffc-neymar-jr',
    name: 'FFC Neymar Jr',
    description: 'Knows a thing or two.',
    key: 'character_redoasisgooseberry',
    icon: 'b74a4677-e2ba-4f25-9e92-25756dafc9d2',
    featured: 'b422fadb-6960-4122-9d3d-37cbc06501e8',
    media_id: '04ddd281-309e-40e5-811d-767e52d84847',
    media_type: 'video/mp4',
    media_uploaded_at: null,
    media_processed_at: 2022-12-02T07:34:43.371Z,
    obtained_type: 'vbucks',
    obtained_value: '1200',
    rating_good: 101,
    rating_bad: 6,
    list_order: 6396,
    list_ranking: {
      default: 6807,
      last_1_hr: 534,
      last_24_hrs: 6807,
      last_7_days: 7682
    },
    estimated_available_combos: 6,
    is_released: true,
    is_active: true,
    is_removed: false,
    modified_at: null,
    created_at: 2022-11-30T17:36:06.643Z,
    type: { slug: 'outfit', name: 'Outfit', key: 'AthenaCharacter' },
    rarity: {
      slug: 'rare',
      name: 'Rare',
      key: 'EFortRarity::Rare',
      color: '28C4F2'
    },
    serie: {
      slug: 'icon',
      name: 'Icon Series',
      key: 'CreatorCollabSeries',
      color: '5DD6EA'
    },
    sets: {
      slug: 'set01',
      name: 'Fortnite Football Club',
      key: 'SphereKickGroup',
      is_active: false
    },
    introduction: {
      slug: 'chapter-3-season-4',
      name: 'Introduced in Chapter 3, Season 4.',
      key: 22,
      chapter: '3',
      season: '4'
    }
  }
]
```

`

How is this possible?

Thanks,
Sam

Tried to rebuild indexes, restarted all Mongo instances, restarted the api servers, removed the items and added them back.

Comment: [`"$unwind"` _"Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element."_](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)  So, when you `"$unwind"`, everything in the document, including `"_id"` is replicated for each element of the unwound array.  The aggregation query is doing what you asked it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected outcome when using [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as if there is more than one matching document it will essentially duplicate the whole document, replacing the array with each item in your array as an object.

If you're only expecting a single document to be returned it sounds like the issue is caused by there being more than one matching document from a `$lookup`.

It could be caused by any one of the lookups, but from the output you posted the two `sets` are slightly different so I would start by searching `items_set` to see if there is more than one matching document. If there is then deleting the duplicate should solve the issue.

```bash
db.items_set.find({ key: 'SphereKickGroup' })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really thought I had an unique index on the "key" value of the "items_set" collection.

In this crash, my system added the value twice.
Thank you again!